# How to salt by one value only in the context of joins?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In the context of optimizing joins with skewed data, I understanding that salting works by duplicating rows in the small table X times and then appending a salt ID to the join key(s). Then when I append a random salt ID to each row in the big table with skewed data, the row matching can happen because each salt ID will have its own copy of the entire dataset in the small table.

However, is it necessary to duplicate the entire dataset in the small table, if we know the exact cause of skew? For example, if we know that there is one value for the join key that creates skew, would it make sense to salt only on this value?

Comment: If you know the value your key is skewed on then it is easier to deal with skew using key isolation.

Comment: If you can filter these skwed data by id, why not split the dataset to two part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, data skewness is a problem in data pipelines, not one shot processing. So any problem that can happen once, can happen again. (Never assume inputs are stable...)

By putting your whole data through this process, you eliminate the risk of having to do it again for a different key.

But essentially, yes, you could just filter out the problematic key, and deal with it separately. However I wouldn't recommend using the salt mechanic in that case. Simply do two different joins (one for the key, and one for the other keys), and `union` the resulting dataframes.

**On another note**, if you have control over your infrastructure, Spark3 introduced [Adaptive Query Execution](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#adaptive-query-execution) which has built-in skew join optimization.